# ESSEXCLN.XXL file not found

Tags: essbase

I am trying to create a macro that connects me to Essbase at the push of a button and am using the syntax found here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_client.pdf

I keep getting the error message that Essexcln.xll is not found. Is there any way around this error? I have done a file search on my computer and the file is no where to be found.

This is the full code I am using.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function EssVConnect Lib "ESSEXCLN.XLL" (ByVal sheetName As Variant, ByVal username As Variant, ByVal password As Variant, ByVal server As Variant, ByVal application As Variant, ByVal database As Variant) As Long
Sub Conn()
 X = EssVConnect(Null, "email@email.com", "password", "http:", "h", "hg6")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have Smart View installed, but not the classic Excel add-in, which was the predecessor to Smart View. In order to find that .XLL file, you'll need to install the old add-in. Do note that it is not officially supported anymore. That are equivalent functions in the Smart View plugin that you can use instead. There is at least one alternative to the classic Excel add-in if you are looking for full VBA compatibility: the Dodeca Excel Add-in, although it is not free.

Comment: That is correct. The office no longer gives us the classic add-in. Thanks for the heads up.